# restrict text_field to only three values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an simple app that uses a text_field tag to take in input:

```
 <div><%= f.label :user %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :user %></div>
```

I know I can restrict input by using select field:

```
<div><%= f.label :user %><br />
<%= f.select :user, [ ['user1'], ['user2'], ['user3'] ] %></div>
```

I want to know how I can have the same restrictions as the above select field, applied to my simple text_field above.  (i.e. user1, user2, user3 will still be the only input allowed, but the user on the page will not see user1, user2, user3 via the select field).

EDIT*
I am just looking for a simple validation scheme

Comment: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

Comment: Do you mean to add a validation in your Rails app that only permits these values, or a JavaScript client-side check to force it?

Comment: the validation one but I'm not opposed to the other way

Comment: I feel like there's not really enough information here to give you a good answer. There are multiple possible solutions -- validations on the model, database level constraints (assuming what you're doing is submitting a value for an attribute of a persisted data model), before filters in your controller. Hard to say which one is appropriate for your case without more info.

Comment: I mean any of those ideas are good solutions which I would accept, but the most basic solution is what I was looking for.  I.e. if you simply enter the wrong string, then an error follows.

Comment: What are the valid users? Any user? What is the field for the user that is validated against? Their first/last/username?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`inclusion` validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion):

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :user, inclusion: { in: ['user1', 'user2', 'user3'],
    message: "%{value} is not a valid user" }
end
```